# How to remove the white frame around the background?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview

The code below generates a window with a black background. Unfortunately the background is framed by a thin white line.

I've tried to set other background parameters to black, but it didn't work out.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene


class GraphicsWindow(QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(scene)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(Qt.black)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    graphics_window = GraphicsWindow()
    graphics_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I wanted to create a window with an entirely black background, but it has a thin white frame.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the background color of the QGraphicsView as for example with QPalette:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPalette
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene


class GraphicsWindow(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(scene)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(Qt.black)
        pal = self.palette()
        pal.setColor(QPalette.Window, Qt.black)
        self.setPalette(pal)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    graphics_window = GraphicsWindow()
    graphics_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add css styles inside the init method of your class:

```
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(GraphicsWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(scene)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(Qt.black)

        self.setStyleSheet("border:0px")
```